# pgfplots - How to enlarge a plot when the nodes' coordinates are on/over the edge?

Tags: pgfplots

I am creating a groupplot (at least intend to) with a width 4cm for each plot.

As I'd like to have the values shown via `nodes near coords`, this proves problematic because I can't figure out how to use `enlarge x limits` correctly.
It either pushes the bars together too much so the values are above other values or other bars.
The other case, when using `{0.2,upper}`, moves the bars too much to the left.

**Is there a sound method to it, i.e. not just doing T&E runs at it till it fits?**

(Also, the whole thing seems to be font dependent, but unfortunately I didn't manage to reproduce that so far.)

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
pgfplotstable
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{force-stats.txt}
Stats,Min,MinStdDev,MinCIP95,Max,MaxStdDev,MaxCIP95
Fx,-7.35,2,2.26,6,1,1
Fy,-4,0.95,0.76,5,1.91,1.5
Fz,-2,1.42,1,4,4,3
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{force-stats.txt}{\tableabcdef}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis=true,
width=4cm,
height=6cm,
%
xlabel={Force components},
ylabel={Force in N},
%
ybar,
%
enlarge x limits={0.3},
%
symbolic x coords={Fx,Fy,Fz},
%
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
xticklabels={{\(F_{x}\)},{\(F_{y}\)},{\(F_{z}\)}},
%
legend columns={1},
legend style={at={(0,0)},anchor=north,at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.18)}}
]
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={above right}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Max, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\addlegendentry{$F_i^{\text{max}}$, a very long one for the problem}
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={below right}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Min, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\addlegendentry{$F_i^{\text{min}}$, test text text}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use something like

```
enlarge x limits={abs={11pt+1ex}},
enlarge y limits={abs={5pt+1em}},
```

The the standard `bar width` is 10pt and the standard shift between the bars is 2pt. Therefore the `enlarge x limits` `abs` value must be at least 11pt.

The `enlarge y limits` should take into account the sep (in the following example 5pt) and the height of the `nodes near coords`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
pgfplots,
pgfplotstable
}

\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{beramono}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{force-stats.txt}
Stats,Min,MinStdDev,MinCIP95,Max,MaxStdDev,MaxCIP95
Fx,-7.35,2,0.36,6,1,0.4
Fy,-4,0.95,0.76,5,1.91,0.5
Fz,-2,1.42,0.5,4,4,0.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{force-stats.txt}{\tableabcdef}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
scale only axis=true,
width=4cm,
height=5cm,
%
xlabel={Force components},
ylabel={Force in N},
%
ybar,
%
enlarge x limits={abs={11pt+1ex}},
enlarge y limits={abs={5pt+1em}},
%
symbolic x coords={Fx,Fy,Fz},
%
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
xticklabels={{\(F_{x}\)},{\(F_{y}\)},{\(F_{z}\)}},
%
legend columns={1},
legend style={anchor=north,at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.25)}, legend cell align={left}},
]
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={above=5pt}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Max, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\addlegendentry{$F_i^{\text{max}}$, a very long one for the problem}
\addplot+[nodes near coords align={below=5pt}] plot [error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit] table [col sep=comma, x=Stats, y=Min, y error=MinCIP95] {\tableabcdef};
\addlegendentry{$F_i^{\text{min}}$, test text text}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, I have changed the `nodes near coords align` to 5pt above/below and the position of the legend.